# SOLVED Rubik's cube third Rotation stops working properly

Tags: keyframes

I'm experiencing a problem with Blender rotation keyframes. When I try to rotate a group of cubes, the first 2 keyframes fork correctly then the 3rd casually breaks. I don't know what could be the problem. Here's a video:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Here's the link --> [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1jXadAx4" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1jXadAx4/)

Comment: the file you shared has a cube but does not rotate. please share the file with your animation as shown in your video.

Comment: Just solved the problem, there were some parts of the cube with different rotation engines, so the animations broken into itself. Thank you for the help anyway have a great day!

Comment: it would be nice for the community to know the exact solution to your problem. could you kindly share it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'll link the file with the solution in a minute.

Comment: Here it is --> [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=wOXsRLoL" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/wOXsRLoL/)

Comment: Exactly the problem was that some cubes had the "XYZ Euler" rotation engine and some had the "Quaternion XWYZ" (the one I needed to make this animation). I just changed all the cubes to the Quaternion XWYZ and everything started working fine.

Comment: very good, exactly you need the quaternion rotational system.